# Execute javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used a script I have found. Where it should do some thing when the mouse hovers over the element

```
    $this.hover(
        function () {
            tip.html("<p>" + tTitle + "</p>");
            setTip(tTop, tLeft);
            setTimer();
        },
        function () {
            stopTimer($this);
            tip.hide();
        }
    );
```

But i want to execute it, without I have to hover the mouse over the element?

How can I do that?

Comment: That script doesn't tell anybody anything. You'd have to show us more to get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can pull the code out of the function:

```
tip.html("<p>" + tTitle + "</p>");
setTip(tTop, tLeft);
setTimer();
```

Answer (score 1):

To trigger the hover on:

```
$this.trigger('mouseover');
```

To trigger the hover out:

```
$this.trigger('mouseout');
```

Another choice is to move the definition outside of the callback, and do it like this:

```
function onMouseOver() {
    tip.html("<p>" + tTitle + "</p>");
    setTip(tTop, tLeft);
    setTimer();
}

function onMouseOut() {
    stopTimer($this);
    tip.hide();
}

// bind the hover event

$this.hover(onMouseOver, onMouseOut);

// or use them manually:

onMouseOver();
onMouseOut();
```

Comment: `.hover()` maps to `mouseneter` and `mouseleave`, rather than `mouseover` and `mouseout` :)

Comment: I'm fairly sure that triggering `mouseover` and `mouseout` trigger the hover events.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to pull the code out of the function, but that didn't help.
But the problem was that i tried to call a function that hadn't been initialized yet.

Sorry for the inconvenience, and thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to run outside of the hover be sure to enclose the function calls in a $(document).ready or your elements wont be ready without the DOM loaded